# How can I safely check a main thread flag from another thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2009

I found this code on the net and it's working but I'm not sure if it's ok to directly read the variable in the main thread from another thread. In this example the flag (variable) is *CancelCopy*.
In general, I want to know how can I read the state of a variable from the main thread in another thread but immediately, without waiting.

```
type
  TCopyEx = packed record
    Source: String;
    Dest: String;
    Handle: THandle;
  end;
  PCopyEx = ^TCopyEx;

const
  CFEX_CANCEL          = WM_USER + 1;

var
  CancelCopy:Boolean=False;

function CopyFileProgress(TotalFileSize, TotalBytesTransferred, StreamSize,
   StreamBytesTransferred: LARGE_INTEGER; dwStreamNumber, dwCallbackReason: DWORD;
   hSourceFile, hDestinationFile: THandle; lpData: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
begin
 if CancelCopy then begin
  SendMessage(THandle(lpData), CFEX_CANCEL, 0, 0);
  result:=PROGRESS_CANCEL;
  Exit;
 end;
 //rest of the code here.......
end;

function CopyExThread(p: PCopyEx):Integer;
var
  Source: String;
  Dest: String;
  Handle: THandle;
  Cancel: PBool;
begin
 Source:=p.Source;
 Dest:=p.Dest;
 Handle:=p.Handle;
 Cancel:=PBOOL(False);
 CopyFileEx(PChar(Source), PChar(Dest), @CopyFileProgress, Pointer(Handle), Cancel, COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING);
 Dispose(p);
 result:=0;
end;

procedure TFormMain.ButtonCopyClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Params: PCopyEx;
  ThreadID: Cardinal;
begin
  cancelCopy := False;
  New(Params);
  Params.Source := EditOriginal.Text;
  Params.Dest := EditCopied.Text;
  Params.Handle := Handle;
  CloseHandle(BeginThread(nil, 0, @CopyExThread, Params, 0, ThreadID));
end;

procedure TFormMain.ButtonCancelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  cancelCopy := true;
end;
```

Comment: It's fine. There is potential for a data race, but it is benign.

Comment: Because the thread is only reading ?

Comment: You say "the thread", but there are two threads in play. Whilst you may know one to be main, and one to be worker, the system just sees two threads. One thread reads that variable, and the other writes it. That's a data race. However, the race is benign.

Comment: Depends on the variable type. In case of a `Boolean` variable it's safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the code you have shown is fine, and will work as expected.

However, there is a small mistake in it.  You are passing the wrong pointer value to the `pbCancel` parameter of `CopyFileEx()`.  However, your code does not crash because the pointer you are passing is effectively being set to `nil`, and `pbCancel` will accept a `nil` pointer, thus `CopyFileEx()` will ignore the parameter.

What you are *supposed* to do is pass the address of a `BOOL` variable, which you can set to `TRUE` at any time to cancel the copy.  `CopyFileEx()` will monitor that variable for you, you do not need to manually return `PROGRESS_CANCEL` from the callback when the variable is set (return `PROGRESS_CANCEL` if your callback encounters an error not related to the copy itself, and you want to abort the copy as a result of the error).  I would not use a global variable for that, though.  I would use a variable that is local to the Form that is performing the copy.

Try something more like this instead:

```
type
  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    ...
  private
    CancelCopy: BOOL; // <-- BOOL, not Boolean
    ...
  end;

...

type
  TCopyEx = record
    Source: String;
    Dest: String;
    Handle: HWND;
    PCancelCopy: PBOOL;
  end;
  PCopyEx = ^TCopyEx;

const
  CFEX_CANCEL = WM_USER + 1;

function CopyFileProgress(TotalFileSize, TotalBytesTransferred, StreamSize,
   StreamBytesTransferred: LARGE_INTEGER; dwStreamNumber, dwCallbackReason: DWORD;
   hSourceFile, hDestinationFile: THandle; lpData: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
begin
  // no need to watch CancelCopy here...
  // do normal status handling here as needed...
  // use PCopyEx(lpData)^ as needed...
end;

function CopyExThread(p: PCopyEx): Integer;
begin
  try
    if not CopyFileEx(PChar(p.Source), PChar(p.Dest), @CopyFileProgress, p, p.PCancelCopy, COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING) then
    begin
      if GetLastError() = ERROR_REQUEST_ABORTED then
        SendMessage(p.Handle, CFEX_CANCEL, 0, 0);
    end;
  finally
    Dispose(p);
  end;
  Result := 0;
end;

procedure TFormMain.ButtonCopyClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Params: PCopyEx;
  ThreadID: Cardinal;
begin
  New(Params);
  Params.Source := EditOriginal.Text;
  Params.Dest := EditCopied.Text;
  Params.Handle := Handle;
  Params.PCancelCopy := @CancelCopy; // <-- pass address of CancelCopy here...

  CancelCopy := FALSE;
  CloseHandle(BeginThread(nil, 0, @CopyExThread, Params, 0, ThreadID));
end;

procedure TFormMain.ButtonCancelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CancelCopy := TRUE;
end;
```

With that said, something else to watch out for - you are passing the `HWND` from the  `TForm.Handle` property to the thread.  If the `TForm` ever destroys/recreates its `HWND` for any reason (and yes, it can happen) while the thread is still running, the `TCopyEx.Handle` value will be left pointing to an invalid window (or worse, to a new window that reuses the old `HWND` value).

In general, the `TWinControl.Handle` property is not thread-safe, and so for that reason alone, it is not a good idea to pass the `HWND` of a `TWinControl` object to a worker thread, unless you can *guarantee* the `HWND` will not be destroyed while the thread is running (and in this example, that is not guaranteed).

In this example, I would use a different `HWND` that is guaranteed to be persistent for the life of the thread, such as the `TApplication.Handle` window (messages sent to this window can be handled via [`TApplication.HookMainWindow()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HookMainWindow)), or the result of calling [`AllocateHWnd()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.AllocateHWnd).

For example:

```
type
  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    ...
  private
    CancelCopy: BOOL; // <-- BOOL, not Boolean
    CopyFileExWnd: HWND;
    procedure CopyFileExWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
    ...
  end;

...

type
  TCopyEx = record
    Source: String;
    Dest: String;
    Handle: HWND;
    PCancelCopy: PBOOL;
  end;
  PCopyEx = ^TCopyEx;

const
  CFEX_CANCEL = WM_USER + 1;

function CopyFileProgress(TotalFileSize, TotalBytesTransferred, StreamSize,
   StreamBytesTransferred: LARGE_INTEGER; dwStreamNumber, dwCallbackReason: DWORD;
   hSourceFile, hDestinationFile: THandle; lpData: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
begin
  ...
end;

function CopyExThread(p: PCopyEx): Integer;
begin
  try
    if not CopyFileEx(
      PChar(p.Source), PChar(p.Dest), @CopyFileProgress, p, p.PCancelCopy, COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING) then
    begin
      if GetLastError() = ERROR_REQUEST_ABORTED then
        SendMessage(p.Handle, CFEX_CANCEL, 0, 0);
    end;
  finally
    Dispose(p);
  end;
  Result := 0;
end;

procedure TFormMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CopyFileExWnd <> 0 then
    DeallocateHWnd(CopyFileExWnd);
end;

procedure TFormMain.ButtonCopyClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Params: PCopyEx;
  ThreadID: Cardinal;
begin
  if CopyFileExWnd = 0 then
    CopyFileExWnd := AllocateHWnd(CopyFileExWndProc);

  New(Params);
  Params.Source := EditOriginal.Text;
  Params.Dest := EditCopied.Text;
  Params.Handle := CopyFileExWnd;
  Params.PCancelCopy := @CancelCopy;

  CancelCopy := FALSE;
  CloseHandle(BeginThread(nil, 0, @CopyExThread, Params, 0, ThreadID));
end;

procedure TFormMain.ButtonCancelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CancelCopy := TRUE;
end;

procedure TFormMain.CopyFileExWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    CFEX_CANCEL: begin
      ...
    end;
    ...
  else
    Message.Result := DefWindowProc(CopyFileExWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
  end;
end;
```